# Web App in iOS 7 URI not working

Tags: web-applications, web, ios7

iOS 7 seems to have an issue with my web app by not opening the URI.
In the code I will point a link to: `pdfehttp://yourname.link.com`

This is the URI for PDF Expert.

It works absolutely fine on iOS 6 but not on iOS 7.
Does anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been a known bug since early beta - any link from full screen web apps that is not http or https does not work, at all. No mailto:, no tel:, and no app links. Also opening a new window with target="_blank" does not work at all. There are no known workarounds.

It is not known when or if this will be fixed, I'd recommend you use whatever means you may have to ensure Apple's iOS and Safari teams hear as many complaints as possible about this to put pressure on getting a fix in place ASAP.

EDIT: Fixed as of iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I must say that it is quite backwards that Apple would remove / not test a key feature like that.